# How do I add some multiplayer code (for java) that does simple things like updates clients' positions

Tags: java, lwjgl, multiplayer

How do I add some code into my multiplayer game that I am creating using ThinMatrix's tutorials on YouTube? I have been following his tutorials when I decided to go... well... on a tangent and start adding my own things to my game. Could someone help me with some code that updates the position of player entities in the game? I already know how to do (basic) networking.

Thank you!

---

Edit: Code added from comments

Camera Class:

```
package entities;

import org.lwjgl.input.Keyboard;
import org.lwjgl.input.Mouse;
import org.lwjgl.util.vector.Vector3f;

public class Camera {

    private float distanceFromPlayer = 35;
    private float angleAroundPlayer = 0;

    private Vector3f position = new Vector3f(0, 0, 0);
    private float pitch = 20;
    private float yaw = 0;
    private float roll;

    private Player player;

    public Camera(Player player){
        this.player = player;
    }

    public void move(){
        calculateZoom();
        calculatePitch();
        calculateAngleAroundPlayer();
        float horizontalDistance = calculateHorizontalDistance();
        float verticalDistance = calculateVerticalDistance();
        calculateCameraPosition(horizontalDistance, verticalDistance);
        this.yaw = 180 - (player.getRotY() + angleAroundPlayer);
    }

    public Vector3f getPosition() {
        return position;
    }

    public float getPitch() {
        return pitch;
    }

    public float getYaw() {
        return yaw;
    }

    public float getRoll() {
        return roll;
    }

    private void calculateCameraPosition(float horizDistance, float verticDistance){
        float theta = player.getRotY() + angleAroundPlayer;
        float offsetX = (float) (horizDistance * Math.sin(Math.toRadians(theta)));
        float offsetZ = (float) (horizDistance * Math.cos(Math.toRadians(theta)));
        position.x = player.getPosition().x - offsetX;
        position.z = player.getPosition().z - offsetZ;
        position.y = player.getPosition().y + verticDistance + 4;
    }

    private float calculateHorizontalDistance(){
        return (float) (distanceFromPlayer * Math.cos(Math.toRadians(pitch+4)));
    }

    private float calculateVerticalDistance(){
        return (float) (distanceFromPlayer * Math.sin(Math.toRadians(pitch+4)));
    }

    private void calculateZoom(){
        float zoomLevel = Mouse.getDWheel() * 0.03f;
        distanceFromPlayer -= zoomLevel;
        if(distanceFromPlayer<5){
            distanceFromPlayer = 5;
        }
    }

    private void calculatePitch(){
        if(Mouse.isButtonDown(1)){
            float pitchChange = Mouse.getDY() * 0.2f;
            pitch -= pitchChange;
            if(pitch < 0){
                pitch = 0;
            }else if(pitch > 90){
                pitch = 90;
            }
        }
    }

    private void calculateAngleAroundPlayer(){
        if(Mouse.isButtonDown(0)){
            float angleChange = Mouse.getDX() * 0.3f;
            angleAroundPlayer -= angleChange;
        }
    }




}
```

Player Class:

```
package entities;

import models.TexturedModel;

import org.lwjgl.input.Keyboard;
import org.lwjgl.util.vector.Vector3f;

import renderEngine.DisplayManager;
import terrains.Terrain;

public class Player extends Entity {

    private static final float RUN_SPEED = 40;
    private static final float TURN_SPEED = 160;
    private static final float GRAVITY = -50;
    private static final float JUMP_POWER = 18;

    private float currentSpeed = 0;
    private float currentTurnSpeed = 0;
    private float upwardsSpeed = 0;

    private boolean isInAir = false;

    public Player(TexturedModel model, Vector3f position, float rotX, float rotY, float rotZ,
            float scale) {
        super(model, position, rotX, rotY, rotZ, scale);
    }

    public void move(Terrain terrain) {
        checkInputs();
        super.increaseRotation(0, currentTurnSpeed * DisplayManager.getFrameTimeSeconds(), 0);
        float distance = currentSpeed * DisplayManager.getFrameTimeSeconds();
        float dx = (float) (distance * Math.sin(Math.toRadians(super.getRotY())));
        float dz = (float) (distance * Math.cos(Math.toRadians(super.getRotY())));
        super.increasePosition(dx, 0, dz);
        upwardsSpeed += GRAVITY * DisplayManager.getFrameTimeSeconds();
        super.increasePosition(0, upwardsSpeed * DisplayManager.getFrameTimeSeconds(), 0);
        float terrainHeight = terrain.getHeightOfTerrain(getPosition().x, getPosition().z);
        if (super.getPosition().y < terrainHeight) {
            upwardsSpeed = 0;
            isInAir = false;
            super.getPosition().y = terrainHeight;
        }
    }

    private void jump() {
        if (!isInAir) {
            this.upwardsSpeed = JUMP_POWER;
            isInAir = true;
        }
    }

    private void checkInputs() {
        if (Keyboard.isKeyDown(Keyboard.KEY_W)) {
            this.currentSpeed = RUN_SPEED;
        } else if (Keyboard.isKeyDown(Keyboard.KEY_S)) {
            this.currentSpeed = -RUN_SPEED;
        } else {
            this.currentSpeed = 0;
        }

        if (Keyboard.isKeyDown(Keyboard.KEY_D)) {
            this.currentTurnSpeed = -TURN_SPEED;
        } else if (Keyboard.isKeyDown(Keyboard.KEY_A)) {
            this.currentTurnSpeed = TURN_SPEED;
        } else {
            this.currentTurnSpeed = 0;
        }

        if (Keyboard.isKeyDown(Keyboard.KEY_SPACE)) {
            jump();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Show us what you have tried so far because we cannot help without code. (Also break down your question into parts and ask one thing at a time). Without code we have all sorts of questions, for example: How are the player entities exposed/managed? Is your problem networking related or a java method issue? Are player entities a custom class? Have you got methods set up so that the player entities can be moved with a method call?

Comment: Could I provide the code from a download link because there are like 20 classes. And yes I do hav some kind of user input system that moves the character around and a system that moves the camera around. I cannot figure out how to do things such as send huge amounts of bytes such as the world, the skybox, and the entities. By custom made if you mean that I created them myself, then yes. Um no. But if you want, I can give you a download link. Thanks for responding

Comment: No one here will look through so much code. You need to narrow your question down to a specific issue. For sending data think about what the smallest amount you can send would be. For example when dealing with movement you really only need to send x, y, z coordinates for location with pitch and yaw for viewing direction, and this can be updated over a tcp or udp connection with very little data sent. You also need to have code to send and then interpret what you send/receive, but it's not a matter of sending huge amounts of info, but rather sending smart info. It's a really big topic....

Comment: Ok... just tell me what code that you would like and I will give it to you.

Comment: I suggest reading through the official Java tutorial on custom networking because it has all the answers you need for basic sending and receiving over a network: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/index.html and more specifically look into sockets: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/index.html

Comment: What we need to see is your basic networking code (sending and receiving), and your player entity class

Comment: It was deleted because the power went out at my house deleting my code.  I will create some more. Here is my player class by the way.

Comment: Ok I will look at it. How do I post some of my code for the player class?

Comment: It is 3rd person by the way

Comment: Edit your original question and paste the code. Dont forget to put it in the code tags

Comment: Camera Class:https://www.dropbox.com/s/4r5tybhw9yr8yx3/Camera%20class.txt?dl=0

Comment: Player class:https://www.dropbox.com/s/if2ipk7tg7b94as/Player%20class.txt?dl=0

Comment: Sorry... I don't know of any other way to do it.

Comment: Please continue discussion for this question here: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145506/question-44252918

Comment: Never mind ignore that link, you do not yet have enough reputation to be able to chat there.

Comment: Here is my new networking code...

Comment: Client:https://www.dropbox.com/s/130bk9jlqijgmju/Client.txt?dl=0

Comment: Server:https://www.dropbox.com/s/i32fwj125u6y6xq/Server.txt?dl=0

Comment: The only problem with my Server/Client code is that they return Socket Exception after they do what they are supposed to do.....

Comment: The socket exception happens because you use `serverSocket.close();` inside the while loop. You should only use `close()` after the while loop. Also this issue has become too big, so I will not be able to answer the question because I need even more info. Please make a new specific question just about your client and server code, and you can ask how to send position data like x, y, z, rotation, pitch (DO NOT send an entire terrain or player object). Once you know how to do that then you can ask another question about how to use that with a player entity. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

The task you want to achieve is a simple one, but because of the way your code is written it has become an unnecessarily hard task to achieve. Fixing your code is not something that you are ready for without understanding more about Object Oriented code and efficient networking.

So at this point I will not attempt to fix your code but I will simply suggest a way to make it work somewhat, and be aware that you will have a lot of issues later if you continue this project.

First we need a simple way to deal with updating the position of a `Player` entity. We can do this by adding a method to your Player class a bit like so:

```
public void moveByFloatInput(fload newX, float newY, float newY) {
    //Here you need to get the current terrain object for this player entity
    Terrain currentTerrain = getTerrain();
    //Now update the terrain object with your new x,y,z points (not sure what methods Terrain contains, you may need to make changes or expose more variables)
    currentTerrain.setNewPosition(newX, newY, newZ);
    //Now call the normal move method using the updated terrain with a new position
    move(updatedTerrainObject);
}
```

Note: there may be a better way to do this, but I have no idea how the terrain class is constructed, and what methods can be called. Also note that you will want to pass the direction the player is looking, but to keep this example simple I have not included any of that.

Now when we receive the x y and z info from a client/server we can update a player entity, for example if you where using an InputStreamReader (not the best idea, but it will help you get started):

```
float x;
float y;
float z;
while ((message = myBufferedReaderInputFromSocket.readLine()) != null) {
    if (message != null) {
        //check if X
        if (message.startsWith("moveX"))
            //save new X so we can update a player entity
            x = Float.parseFloat(message.substring(5));
        //check if Y
        if (message.startsWith("moveY"))
            //save new Y so we can update a player entity
            y = Float.parseFloat(message.substring(5));
        //check if Z
        if (message.startsWith("moveZ"))
            //save new Z so we can update a player entity
            z = Float.parseFloat(message.substring(5));
    }
    //when x, y and y all have a new position we can update a player entity
    if(x != null && y != null && z != null)
    {
        //call our new player move method and change that player entities position
        playerEntityForThisSocket.moveByFloatInput(x, y, z);
        //reset x,y,z to null so that the server can receive the next movement
        x = null;
        y = null;
        z = null;
    }
}
```

Then for sending over a socket you can do it a bit like:

```
//you could create a Print writer for your socket:
PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream(), true);
//then simply send a players new position info
//inculde the "moveX" keyword before the Float x,y,z so that the server/client at the other end knows how to process the info:
out.println(moveX + newXposition);
out.println(moveY + newYposition);
out.println(moveZ + newZposition);
```

If this does not make sense then I suggest that you complete the basic Java tutorials before you continue coding, because the tutorials contain the essential building blocks of coding with Java, and with that knowledge that you can build on to make a great project, but without that knowledge you are doomed to have never ending issues:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/index.html

Comment: I have gotten there quite a few times but I seem to mess up there.

Comment: What is all good and well... but how do I get the client to send the other players stuff? Such as the world position? I commented my newest client and server code that I just finished typing. I hope that it helps

Answer (score 0):

You need to make it so your player class can return the current locations and doing so makes things easy as all you need to do is create another instance of the game with new packages and run it but on the server end you need to send the players current location and make this update consistently as this would use a coordinate system but this is very basic so you will already need an entity in the game such as a player entity in the server side of the game and doing so you need this entity to update its position so you could do something like player.getPosition() and then serverSideModel = player.getPosition() as it would set both models to the same position if that makes sence